# Data.table conditional merges

Tags: r, data.table

I want to merge two data.tables using a condition on a variable in dt1. See the following example:

```
library(data.table)

# Example data tables
dt1 <- data.table(id = 1:5, var1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1), name1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
dt2 <- data.table(name2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), other_var = 101:105)
```

```
> dt1
   id var1 name1
1:  1    1     A
2:  2    0     B
3:  3    1     C
4:  4    0     D
5:  5    1     E
> dt2
   name2 other_var
1:     A       101
2:     B       102
3:     C       103
4:     D       104
5:     E       105
```

What I would like to do is merge dt1 and dt2 such that a value is merged only if var1 == 1 in dt1. Desired result:

```
> dt1
   id var1 name1  other_var
1:  1    1     A       101
2:  2    0     B        NA
3:  3    1     C       103
4:  4    0     D        NA
5:  5    1     E       105
```

I've tried something like:

```
dt1[var1 == 1][dt2, other_var := i.other_var, on = .(name1 = name2)]
```

and

```
dt1[dt2, on = .(name1 = name2), other_var := i.other_var, var1 == 1]
```

but neither approach seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
dt1[dt2,
    other_var := replace(other_var, !var1, NA),
    on = .(name1 = name2)
]
```

or

```
dt1[dt2,
    other_var := NA^(!var1) * other_var,
    on = .(name1 = name2)
]
```

which gives

```
   id var1 name1 other_var
1:  1    1     A       101
2:  2    0     B        NA
3:  3    1     C       103
4:  4    0     D        NA
5:  5    1     E       105
```

Comment: I've seen `NA[..]` and `NA*` before, but never `NA^..` before, that's a neat trick. Nice!

Answer (score 7):

You are expressing a condition by which you want to join, so set `dt2[, var1 := 1]` then join on `var1` as well as well as name:

```r
dt2[, var1 := 1]

dt1[dt2,
    on = .(name1 = name2, var1),
    other_var := i.other_var
][]

#       id  var1  name1 other_var
#    <int> <num> <char>     <int>
# 1:     1     1      A       101
# 2:     2     0      B        NA
# 3:     3     1      C       103
# 4:     4     0      D        NA
# 5:     5     1      E       105
```

This should be reasonably fast. If adding the column is a problem just remove it after the join (`dt2[, var1 := NULL]`).

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

```
dt1[var1 == 1][dt2, other_var := i.other_var, on = .(name1 = name2)]
```

This returns a filtered table `dt1[var1 == 1]`, then joins it with `dt2` in a second `[]`, so the other rows of `dt1` never make it through.

```
dt1[dt2, on = .(name1 = name2), other_var := i.other_var, var1 == 1]
```

Here, `var1 == 1` is the third unnamed argument, so gets parsed as the `by` expression of `DT[i,j,by]`. This suggests (I suppose) that we want to perform the join in two blocks according to whether `var1` is or isn't equal to 1, which doesn't express the intention (and in any case throws an error).

The solutions given either amount to a condition on the RHS of `other_var :=` so that it gives `NA` when `var1 != 1`, or else involve a "trick" second join-column so that nothing joins to the rows of `dt1` where `var1 != 1` in the first place. A non-connoisseur's solution (essentially just as fast) is to do the join naively, then overwrite with `NA`s in a second `[]` step:

```
dt1[dt2, on = .(name1 = name2), other_var := i.other_var][var1==1, other_var := NA]
```